# installing old MySQL client libraries (libmysqlclient.so.15, libpq.so.4)

Tags: mysql, nagios, zimbra, libraries

I'm attempting to install Nagios plugins on a Zimbra 8.0.2 server running CentOS 6.4, but have run into the following error when I run `yum install nagios-plugins-all`

```
Error: Package: nagios-plugins-mysql-1.4.15-2.el5.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libmysqlclient.so.15()(64bit)
Error: Package: nagios-plugins-pgsql-1.4.15-2.el5.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libpq.so.4()(64bit)
Error: Package: nagios-plugins-mysql-1.4.15-2.el5.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libmysqlclient.so.15(libmysqlclient_15)(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

How can I install these libraries (libmysqlclient.so.15 & libpq.so.4)?

Will installing these libraries possibly break Zimbra?

Comment: These should already be available in the base repositories. What changes have been made to them on this server?

Comment: None that I'm aware of. I installed Zimbra 8.0.2 on a fresh CentOS 6.3 install (which has been updated to 6.4 now). And also installed nrpe. I've also installed the EPEL repo.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I had to remove some cached packages:

Resolved this by running:

```
yum clean all
```

then

```
yum clean metadata
```

the latest version of nagios-plugins (`1.4.16-5.el6.x86_64.rpm`) was then available via the epel repo when running `yum install nagios-plugins-all`

Comment: nice, this answer fixed the same issue in centos 7